Export DXF from QGIS with Symbology and Fill for Points in PyQGIS
I'm trying to export multiple vector layers from QGIS to a DXF file using PyQGIS. The export mostly works, but I’m running into issues with points. Currently, points are exported as simple circles or blocks in AutoCAD, but they don't retain their fill color or correct size from QGIS. I would like the points to be exported as filled circles with the appropriate color.
What I've Tried:
I'm using QgsDxfExport to set up the export and am retrieving the colors of point layers to apply them during the export process. I create the DXF layers for lines and points and tried using buildDataDefinedBlocks() to handle points. However, in AutoCAD, the points only show as small circles with a hatch in the center, without the expected fill.
Here’s the current code I’m using to set up the export:
def on_export_dxf_clicked(self):
    # Get the layers from QGIS project
    layers = [layer for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values() 
              if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer and "Client Pin" not in layer.name()]
    
    if not layers:
        QMessageBox.critical(self, "Error", "No vector layers found for DXF export.")
        return
    
    # Dictionary to store colors for point layers
    point_layer_colors = {}

    for layer in layers:
        if layer.geometryType() == QgsWkbTypes.PointGeometry:
            renderer = layer.renderer()
            symbol = renderer.symbol()
            if symbol:
                # Get the color from the symbol
                color = symbol.color()
                point_layer_colors[layer.name()] = QColor(color.red(), color.green(), color.blue())
    
    export_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "export_network.dxf")
    
    # Create the DXF export object
    dxfExport = QgsDxfExport()

    # Prepare the layers for export
    dxf_layers = []
    
    for layer in layers:
        if layer.geometryType() == QgsWkbTypes.LineGeometry:
            renderer = layer.renderer()
            if renderer.symbol():
                renderer.symbol().setWidth(1.0)  # 2 units for polylines
        elif layer.geometryType() == QgsWkbTypes.PointGeometry:
            color = point_layer_colors.get(layer.name(), QColor("black"))
            dxf_layer = QgsDxfExport.DxfLayer(layer)
            buildPoint = dxf_layer.buildDataDefinedBlocks()
            renderer = layer.renderer()
            if renderer.symbol():
                renderer.symbol().setSize(2.0)
        
        dxf_layers.append(QgsDxfExport.DxfLayer(layer))
    
    dxfExport.addLayers(dxf_layers)
    dxfExport.setSymbologyScale(2000)
    dxfExport.setSymbologyExport(QgsVectorFileWriter.SymbologyExport.PerSymbolLayer)
    dxfExport.setLayerTitleAsName(-1)
    dxfExport.setDestinationCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:2154"))
    dxfExport.setForce2d(1)
    
    if os.path.exists(export_path):
        if not self.is_file_accessible(export_path, 'w'):
            QMessageBox.critical(self, "Error", f"The DXF file '{export_path}' is currently locked or open in another program.")
            return
    
    try:
        dxfFile = QFile(export_path)
        dxfExport.writeToFile(dxfFile, 'CP1252')
        QMessageBox.information(self, "Success", f"DXF export was successful to {export_path}.")
        
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Open File', f"Do you want to open the exported DXF file ({export_path})?", 
                                     QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            self.open_dxf_file(export_path)
    except OSError as e:
        QMessageBox.critical(self, "File Error", f"File-related error: {str(e)}")
    except Exception as e:
        QMessageBox.critical(self, "Error", f"DXF export failed: {str(e)}")

What I’m Looking to Achieve:
I'd like to make sure that the points in the DXF file are exported as filled circles, with the fill color corresponding to the layer's symbol color in QGIS. I tried using QgsDxfExport.writeCircleV2 and writePointV2, but the points only show up as small circles with a hatch point in AutoCAD.
Specific Question:
How can I ensure that points are exported as filled circles with the appropriate color?

One question per Question, please, as per the [Tour]. Questions with a bullet list titled "Questions" are not likely to get reopen votes.

I had rewritten the question, how I can send to review again ?

It is in review, but you still have three questions in the block labelled "Specific questions", which is two too many.
